# Can a separate process be started from within a flask controller by using the multiprocessing library?

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

**Problem:**

I have been trying to use the multiprocessing library (anaconda - python3) in a flask application. The goal is to start a process asynchronously after clicking some button in the web page. To that end, the webpage button fires a function in a controller:

```
@module.route('/start_long_process', methods=['POST'])
def start_long_process():
     ...
     # Start process async
     p = Process(target=some_function)
     p.start()
     ...
```

If I then afterwards check whether the process is alive by doing this:

```
     print(p.pid)
     print(p.is_alive())
```

the *pid* and *True* value are returned.

However, it seems as if the function never actually started. Any print or simply write to file command does not take place. While when I try to run this same function by using a multiprocessing Process not being in the flask application it does do what is expected.

I know preferably something as *Celery* is used in combination with flask and multi-threaded tasks but that would be a lot of overhead.

**Question**

Is it not possible to start a separate process from within a flask controller function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using development flask server you can structure your app in a [similar](https://wiki.glitchdata.com/index.php?title=Flask:_Multi-Processing_in_Flask) fashion:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
_pool = None


def wanted_function(x):
    # import packages that is used in this function
    # do your expensive time consuming process
    return x * x


@app.route('/expensive_calc/<int:x>')
def route_expcalc(x):
    f = _pool.apply_async(wanted_function, (x,))
    r = f.get(timeout=2)

    return 'Result is %d' % r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _pool = Pool(processes=4)
    try:
        # insert production server deployment code
        app.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        _pool.close()
        _pool.join()
```

Then you run it with `./<script_name>.py` and you will have both flask app listening and `_pool` available for processes.

However, if you plan on setting up more serious solution you will probably want to use web server with [WSGI](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) support.

In that way, your flask app will not be started as in development server case. That way you won't have access to the `_pool` so you should think to use more serious task queues like `Celery`. [Here](https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html) is the list of all good ones, some of which are easier to set up and use than `Celery`.

#### Windows

In case you are trying to do this on Windows, you will have difficulties.

Apparently, the way child process is started on Windows differs. You can check [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) for more info but this is important part:

> **spawn**
>
> The parent process starts a fresh python interpreter process.
>   The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run
>   the process objects run() method. In particular, unnecessary file
>   descriptors and handles from the parent process will not be inherited.
>   Starting a process using this method is rather slow compared to using
>   fork or forkserver.
>
> Available on Unix and Windows. The default on Windows.
>
> **fork**
>
> The parent process uses os.fork() to fork the Python interpreter.
>   The child process, when it begins, is effectively identical to the
>   parent process. All resources of the parent are inherited by the child
>   process. Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is
>   problematic.
>
> Available on Unix only. The default on Unix.
>
> **forkserver**
>
> When the program starts and selects the forkserver start
>   method, a server process is started. From then on, whenever a new
>   process is needed, the parent process connects to the server and
>   requests that it fork a new process. The fork server process is single
>   threaded so it is safe for it to use os.fork(). No unnecessary
>   resources are inherited.
>
> Available on Unix platforms which support passing file descriptors
>   over Unix pipes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I just noticed the above setup does not give any problems in a Linux environment (Ubuntu). It does on Windows however (to which I'm tied for other reasons). Any idea why that could be?

Comment: I have updated the answer with why this might be difficult on Windows.